Prisma + postgresql extensions on different (database, not Prisma) schema
I'm working on writing a Prisma extension to support pgvector. All seems fine, and I've moved on to writing automated test cases. I've been following this methodology for vitest, which works by attaching to a new, randomly generated schema name for each test suite: DATABASE_URL="postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/pgv-test?schema=<random name>", and running pnpx prisma migrate deploy. The problem is, it seems to be having some issue with the Postgres extension on the random schema:
 RUN  v1.6.0 /Users/cwr/src/prisma-extension-pgvector/package

Error: P3018

A migration failed to apply. New migrations cannot be applied before the error is recovered from. Read more about how to resolve migration issues in a production database: https://pris.ly/d/migrate-resolve

Migration name: 20240614101133_test_init

Database error code: 42704

Database error:
ERROR: type "vector" does not exist

Position:
 27 -- CreateTable
 28 CREATE TABLE "Vector" (
 29     "id" SERIAL NOT NULL,
 30     "metadata" JSONB,
 31     "testfield" TEXT,
 32     "embedding" vector(3),

DbError { severity: "ERROR", parsed_severity: Some(Error), code: SqlState(E42704), message: "type \"vector\" does not exist", detail: None, hint: None, position: Some(Original(755)), where_: None, schema: None, table: None, column: None, datatype: None, constraint: None, file: Some("parse_type.c"), line: Some(270), routine: Some("typenameType") }

I spent a fair bit of time trying to extend the Prisma migration sql to make sure all schemas had access to the extensions (e.g., trying to apply this, or this by manually adjusting the migration.sql file) but can't quite get it to work. This is the native, generated migration.sql file:
-- CreateExtension
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "vector";


-- CreateTable
CREATE TABLE "Vector" (
    "id" SERIAL NOT NULL,
    "metadata" JSONB,
    "testfield" TEXT,
    "embedding" vector(3),

    CONSTRAINT "Vector_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);

What magic do I need to add to get it so that vitest connects to the database at ?schema=foo, it works?

Not sure if this is the best way, but I ended up resolving by combining the two approaches. First, for the init migration:
-- CreateExtensionSchema
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS "extension";

-- make usable by everyone
GRANT usage ON SCHEMA extension TO public;
GRANT execute ON all functions IN SCHEMA extension TO public;
ALTER default privileges IN SCHEMA extension
    GRANT execute ON functions TO public;
ALTER default privileges IN SCHEMA extension
    GRANT usage ON types TO public;

-- CreateExtension
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "vector" SCHEMA extension;

-- set search_path for this session
SET search_path = public,extension;

-- CreateTable
CREATE TABLE "Vector" (
    "id" SERIAL NOT NULL,
    "metadata" JSONB,
    "testfield" TEXT,
    "embedding" vector(3),

    CONSTRAINT "Vector_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);

However, you can't use that migration inside of the vitest process, because it includes "public" in the search path. So, instead of doing prisma migrate deploy, I create another sql file:
-- File: test_schema_config.sql
-- Extend search_path for this session;
DO $$
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE 'SET search_path TO '||current_setting('search_path')||',extension';
    END
$$;

-- CreateTable
CREATE TABLE "Vector" (
    "id" SERIAL NOT NULL,
    "metadata" JSONB,
    "testfield" TEXT,
    "embedding" vector(3),

    CONSTRAINT "Vector_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);

And then inside of the vitest prisma-test-environment.js, instead of doing execSync('pnpx prisma migrate deploy --schema ./test/prisma/schema.prisma');, use the Prisma db execute to run the file: execSync('pnpx prisma db execute --schema ./test/prisma/schema.prisma --file ./test/prisma/test_schema_config.sql');
